# Is there a way to run a function in parallel that takes ndarray as an argument?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool, starmap

I have a function,

`def noflux(j,i,cells,rfu,lfu,ufu,dfu):`

that takes numpy arrays as input and I would like to run this function twice in parallel using the multiprocessing package, i.e.

`noflux(j,i,cells,rfu,lfu,ufu,dfu):`
 `noflux(j,i,cells,rfh,lfh,ufh,dfh):`

this function doesn't return anything but just makes changes to the arguments

Is there a way to do this?